# .htaccess mod_rewrite... I think?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was wondering how in .htaccess I can redirect the following URL:

> /mysite.com/blog/Something => /mysite.com/blog.php?tag=Something

Here is a script I've used on a different site however this is a bit simpilar:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?name=$1
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Click on the `.htaccess`, you created and you will get plenty of answers.

Comment: BTW, you can fold the above two rules into one by using the "optional" operator so `/?` means match 0 or 1 **`/`** characters.  Hence the combined regexp is `^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog.php?tag=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

**Update:** As per your comment this is the rule you will need:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*) blog.php?tag=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks it works great however is what is the other way where I can add a slash at the end of something i.e. /blog/somehting/ because that rule only applies to strings without it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#/mysite.com/blog/Something to /mysite.com/blog.php?tag=Something
RewriteRule ^blog/(something)$ blog.php?tag=$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

If `something` is a variable then change the rule to

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(\w+)$ blog.php?tag=$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

If you want the URL to stay the same in the Users browser then drop the `R=301` as below

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(\w+)$ blog.php?tag=$1 [L,NC]
```